# Parse $PATH variable and save the directory names into an array of strings

Tags: c, bash, gcc, malloc, strtok

I want to parse the $PATH variable of Linux, and then save the directory names that are getting separated with ':' into an array of strings.

I know it's a simple task but I am stuck and any help would be nice.

My code so far is something like this but something ain't right.

```
char **array;
char *path_string;
char *path_var = getenv("PATH");
int size_of_path_var = strlen(path_var);

path_string = strtok(path_var, ":");
while (path_string != NULL) {
    ss = strlen(path_string)
    array[i] = (char *)malloc(ss + 1);
    array[i] = path_string; //this is actually all i want to do for every path
    i++;
    path_string = strtok(NULL, ":");
}
```

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? With what input have you attempted this?

Comment: You can't use `strtok()`; it will throw away important information about `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:$HOME/bin:` and other variants with a null entry (equivalent to `.`).  You might want to argue that's a good idea; it isn't, however, an accurate parse of PATH.

Comment: From [the `getenv` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html): "As typically implemented, `getenv()` returns a pointer to a string within the environment list.  The caller must take care not to modify this string, since that would change the environment of the process." This is problematic for you since [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) *modifies* the string in tokenizes.

Comment: You haven't allocated any space for `array`, but you're busy assigning into it anyway.  That is not a recipe for happiness.

Comment: you're allocating space for `array[i] = (char *)malloc(ss + 1);` but overwrite it just after. Consider dropping that for `array[i] = strdup(path_string)`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what do you mean about throwing away important information?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: If you have a leading colon `:` in PATH, or two adjacent colons in the middle, or a trailing colon, then there is an implicit `.` entry before, in between, or after the referenced colon — that is, the current directory is on the PATH even though the `.` is not visible in the PATH.  The trouble is, `strtok()` allows multiple adjacent delimiters and doesn't recognize empty fields as a possibility.  You can also have `.:` or `:.:` or `:.` at the start, in the middle or at the end, but that's explicit and `strtok()` wouldn't lose that information.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: However, security advice says "Don't include `.` in your PATH at all".  Hence the observation about arguing it is a good idea to omit the current directory (unless, perhaps, it is explicitly listed).  However, that wouldn't be accurate and you might come up with a false interpretation of what will happen when you execute something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2 main things wrong with your code, pretty much summarized by the comments:

- you strtok a public buffer (returned by `getenv`)
- you don't know how many variables will be in the buffer so you don't allocate the array of arrays at all!

Let me propose a working implementation *not* using strtok, and thus allowing to detect empty path (and replace it by `.` as Jonathan hinted). Compiles without any warnings using `gcc -Wall -Wwrite-strings`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    const char **array;
    const char *orig_path_var = getenv("PATH");
    char *path_var = strdup(orig_path_var ? orig_path_var : ""); // just in case PATH is NULL, very unlikely
    const char *the_dot = ".";
    int j;
    int len=strlen(path_var);
    int nb_colons=0;
    char pathsep = ':';
    int current_colon = 0;

    // first count how many paths we have, and "split" almost like strtok would do
    for (j=0;j<len;j++)
    {
        if (path_var[j]==pathsep)
        {
            nb_colons++;
            path_var[j] = '\0';
        }       
    }

    // allocate the array of strings
    array=malloc((nb_colons+1) * sizeof(*array));

    array[0] = path_var;  // first path

    // rest of paths
    for (j=0;j<len;j++)
    {
        if (path_var[j]=='\0')
        {
            current_colon++;
            array[current_colon] = path_var+j+1;
            if (array[current_colon][0]=='\0')
            {
                // special case: add dot if path is empty
                array[current_colon] = the_dot;
            }

        }
    }

    for (j=0;j<nb_colons+1;j++)
    {
        printf("Path %d: <%s>\n",j,array[j]);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Details of the operations:

- make a copy of the env string to avoid butchering it
- count the colons (to make it work with windows, just replace with `;`) and tokenize
- allocate the array according to number of colons + 1 (1 more token than number of separators!)
- second pass to go through the string again and fill it with parts of the tokenized string (no need to allocate again, the original string is already allocated)
- special case: empty path: replace by `.`. Could display a warning to tell the user that this is not safe.
- print the result

Comment: 2 small issues: If `PATH` starts with `:`, the first entry in the array is an empty string that is not replaced with `"."`.  Also `strdup()` invokes undefined behavior if there is no `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I've fixed the PATH=NULL issue. Will check the other one.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, but I had to do this for a homework assignment and I thought I would share my solution since the above is a bit complicated and doesn't use strtok.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void printStrings(const char* args[]);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    char* path = getenv("PATH");  //gets the path
    const char* pathParts[100];   //arr to hold pointers to parts of path (whatever size)

    char* token; //holds next part of path

    token = strtok(path, ":");
    pathParts[0] = token; // place pointer to next part of path in arr

    int i = 1;
    while(token != NULL) {
        token = strtok(NULL, ":");
        pathParts[i] = token; // place pointer to next part of path in arr
        i++;
    }

    printStrings(pathParts); // print parts of path 1/line

    return 0;
}

void printStrings(const char* args[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while(args[i] != 0) {
        printf("%s\n", args[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use `strtok()` on a string returned from `getenv()` as it will modify the parsed string.  Per [**7.22.4.6 The getenv function**, paragraph 4 of the C11 standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.4.6p4): "The getenv function returns a pointer to a string associated with the matched list member. **The string pointed to shall not be modified by the program** ..."

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I came across what (for me) is the ideal solution. Use this BASH command:

**echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"**

Then, you can capture the output and create your array.