# How to store each sentence as an element of an array?

Tags: c, arrays, string

So, suppose I have an array (program asks me to write some text):

```
char sentences[] = "The first sentence.The second sentence.The third sentence";
```

And I need to store each sentence as an array, where I can have access to any word, or to store the sentences in a single array as elements. 
(sentences[0] = "The first sentence"; sentences[1] = "The second sentence";)

How to print out each sentence separately I know:

```
char* sentence_1 = strtok(sentences, ".");
char* sentence_2 = strtok(NULL, ".");
char* sentence_3 = strtok(NULL, ".");

printf("#1 %s\n", sentence_1);
printf("#2 %s\n", sentence_2);
printf("#3 %s\n", sentence_3);
```

But how to make program store those sentences in 1 or 3 arrays I have no idea. 
Please, help!

Comment: Please look at `strdup`.

Comment: "program asks me to write some text" Have the machines finally risen? Are we the slaves now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you keep it in the `main`, since your `sentences` memory is static (cannot be deleted) you can simply do that:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char sentences[] = "The first sentence.The second sentence.The third sentence";
  char* sentence[3];
  unsigned int i;

  sentence[0] = strtok(sentences, ".");

  for (i=1;i<sizeof(sentence)/sizeof(sentence[0]);i++)
  {
    sentence[i] = strtok(NULL, ".");
  }

  for (i=0;i<sizeof(sentence)/sizeof(sentence[0]);i++)
  {
    printf("%d: %s\n",i,sentence[i]);
  }

  return 0;

}
```

In the general case, you first have to duplicate your input string:

```
char *sentences_dup = strdup(sentences);
sentence[0] = strtok(sentences_dup, ".");
```

many reasons for that:

- you don't know the lifespan/scope of the input, and it is generally a pointer/a parameter, so your sentences could be invalid as soon as the input memory is freed/goes out of scope
- the passed buffer may be `const`: you cannot modify its memory (`strtok` modifies the passed buffer)
- change `sentences[]` by `*sentences` in the example above and you're pointing on a read-only zone: you have to make a copy of the buffer.

Don't forget to store the duplicated pointer, because you may need to free it at some point.
Another alternative is to also duplicate there:

```
  for (i=1;i<sizeof(sentence)/sizeof(sentence[0]);i++)
  {
    sentence[i] = strdup(strtok(NULL, "."));
  }
```

so you can free your big tokenized string at once, and the sentences have their own, independent memory.

EDIT: the remaining problem here is that you still have to know in advance how many sentences there are in your input.

For that, you could count the dots, and then allocate the proper number of pointers.

```
int j,nb_dots=0;
char pathsep = '.';
int nb_sentences;
int len = strlen(sentences);
char** sentence;

// first count how many dots we have
for (j=0;j<len;j++)
{
    if (sentences[j]==pathsep)
    {
        nb_dots++;
    }       
}
nb_sentences = nb_dots+1; // one more!!
// allocate the array of strings
sentence=malloc((nb_sentences) * sizeof(*sentence));
```

now that we have the number of strings, we can perform our `strtok` loop. Just be careful of using `nb_sentences` and not `sizeof(sentence)/sizeof(sentence[0])` which is now irrelevant (worth 1) because of the change of array type.

But at this point you could also get rid of `strtok` completely like proposed in another [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196067/parse-path-variable-and-save-the-directory-names-into-an-array-of-strings/40196300#40196300)