# Compare tokens spaced with space from a string using strtok in c?

Tags: c, c-strings

I need a method to compare a multiple tokens from the same string using strtok, I need to compare the first token with the second token and so on, so i tried this, but unfortunately the first loop executes only once.

```
char s[]="123 456 789"
char *dup1 = strdup(s);
char *dup2 = strdup(s);
for(char* old=strtok(dup1," "); old!=NULL; old=strtok(NULL," ")){
    for(char* new=strtok(dup2," "); new!=NULL; new=strtok(NULL, " ")){
        strcmp(old, new);
    }
    dup2=s;
}
```

Comment: you've got a ton of memory leaks here... and of course the first loop executes only once: it's the _outer_ loop... and what's the use of `strcmp` here? what is the expected output? if it's "no output", then you're done...

Comment: also, you assign `dup2` to `s`, so your duplication only works once. The second time, you change `s` when tokenizing.

Comment: `strcmp` is just for clarification! The main question is can strtok tokenize more than one string at a time

Comment: Oh, sorry. No, `strtok` isn't reentrant. you have to use `strtok_r`

Comment: Or build an array of token pointers first, and then compare their targets with two nested loops.

Comment: I may have some code which does that somewhere. Let me dig: found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196067/parse-path-variable-and-save-the-directory-names-into-an-array-of-strings/40196300#40196300. It avoids strtok and does that manually in 2 passes: first count & tokenize, second: allocate & store tokens.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That helped, though it's easier to use strtok_r